# How To add Child View to a Common View Xamarin Froms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to embed child view to my common parent view as follows

my parent view

```
<Frame CornerRadius="8"
       Padding="0,5,0,5"
       BackgroundColor="Blue">

        <Grid x:Name="SheetGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Text="Test Title"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     HeightRequest="5"
                     WidthRequest="50"
                     BackgroundColor="Red"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     VerticalOptions="Center" />     
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
```

I need to use this as a common view that title will not change but the body getting change.

my usage in Mainpage like below

```
<samplepopup:CommonPopUpView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red" >

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                     x:Name="TestView">
                <Label Text="testing"/>
            </StackLayout>

        </samplepopup:CommonPopUpView>
```

So i need to add the "TestView" as a child of my "Common View"

how can i do that?
Any Help really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For it to work you will need to do a couple of changes to your code.

In your parentView (`CommonPopUpView.xaml`) add a container that will hold your Body, it can be something like this:

```
<ContentView x:Name="BodyContentView"
             Grid.Row="1" />    
</ContentView>
```

With your existing code it should look like this:

```
<Frame CornerRadius="8"
    Padding="0,5,0,5"
    BackgroundColor="Blue">

    <Grid x:Name="SheetGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Test Title"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    HeightRequest="5"
                    WidthRequest="50"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <ContentView x:Name="BodyContentView"
                        Grid.Row="1">
        </ContentView>                    
    </Grid>
</Frame>
```

In the code behind of that file (`CommonPopUpView.xaml.cs`), you will need a `BindableProperty`:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty BodyContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(BodyContent),
    typeof(View),
    typeof(CommonPopUpView),
    null,
    BindingMode.OneWay,
    null,
    OnBodyContentChanged);

public View BodyContent
{
    get => (View)GetValue(BodyContentProperty);
    set => SetValue(BodyContentProperty, value);
}

private static void OnBodyContentChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    if (bindable is CommonPopUpView myCommonPopUpView)
    {
        myCommonPopUpView.BodyContentView.Content = (View) newValue;
    }
}
```

If you want to get more info about BindableProperties you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties)

In that same file, you will also need to add the `ContentProperty` annotation at the class level. It should look like this:

```
[ContentProperty("BodyContent")]
public partial class CommonPopUpView : ContentView
```

That last part is important to prevent your `CommonPopUpView` Content to be overridden making sure that any new content will be set into the Container you prepared (`BodyContentView`).

Now you just need to use it:

```
<controls:CommonPopUpView Margin="6,25">
    <Grid Padding="15">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Stack Overflow"
                FontSize="18"
                TextColor="White"
                FontAttributes="Bold" />
        <Label Text="stack.overflow@internet.com"
                FontSize="12"
                TextColor="WhiteSmoke"
                Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</controls:CommonPopUpView>

<controls:CommonPopUpView Margin="6,15">
    <Grid Padding="15">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Source="xamarin_small"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HeightRequest="100"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Image Source="microsoft.jpg"
                WidthRequest="100"
                HeightRequest="100"
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>            
</controls:CommonPopUpView>
```

Any content that you set inside your `CommonPopUpView` CustomView will be set only in the Body Container keeping the other controls/views you have defined.

[image]

Hope this helps.-

Comment: i am trying add this pop up in a MainPage with a button vertically 
button should be place in the top.
popup should be place in the bottom.
but i do that it tend to invisible he popup.

do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: @ChanduRanwala what's the design you are looking to get? Maybe you ask another question here in StackOverflow so I or another person could help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can read document about [Instantiate a custom control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/contentview#instantiate-a-custom-control).

First, you should add a new `ContentView` let's call it `MyCustomView` to your project:

```
public partial class MyCustomView : ContentView
{
    public MyCustomView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In xaml, add your code there:

```
  <ContentView.Content>
        <samplepopup:CommonPopUpView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red"
                                 >

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                     x:Name="TestView">
                <Label Text="testing"/>
            </StackLayout>

        </samplepopup:CommonPopUpView>
    </ContentView.Content>
```

When you want to use this view in your parent view, declare a reference to the custom view namespace  in your parent page and then use it in the xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:CustomPopUp="clr-namespace:App222"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App222.MainPage">



    <Frame CornerRadius="8"
       Padding="0,5,0,5"
       BackgroundColor="Blue">

        <Grid x:Name="SheetGrid">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Label Text="Test Title"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     HeightRequest="5"
                     WidthRequest="50"
                     BackgroundColor="Red"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                     />

            <CustomPopUp:MyCustomView Grid.Row="1"/>

        </Grid>
    </Frame>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: by this way can not see the title

Comment: @ChanduRanwala Does your problem resolved? If so, can you please mark the answer which will help more people with same problem:).